# HTML image map outside an image

Tags: html, dictionary, image, imagemap, area

I have to generate `<map>` and `<area>` elements on a web page containing many images. Each image would have to be linked to its appropriate `<map>` via `usemap="#map1"`, `usemap="#map2"`, etc...

As a nasty hack for this situation, I'd like to add one 1x1 absolutely positioned (top:0, left:0) `<img>` (the *anchor-image*). Then, I'd combine all the `<area>` tags into one `<map>` (the *super-map*), referenced by the *anchor-image*.

Trying this, the `<area>` tags defined in the *super-map* do not activate when I mouseover them (they are outside of the 1x1 *anchor-image*). I tried making *anchor-image* width:100%, height:100% and playing with its z-index (I still have to interact with the images on the page for other reasons). Unfortunately, when the z-index makes the `<area>` elements clickable, it stops me from interacting with the images.

Any ideas on what else I can try? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you elaborate on why you need so many maps? If you have a lot of images, why not split each one into a single action and simply place them in `a` tags?

Or, why not combine the images into a larger one and then have fewer maps?

Comment: I have to allow clients to 'tag' an image - by drawing rectangles on them to create maps on the fly. They can tag each image more than once. The catch is that there are also many images per page, and I am trying to avoid having to create a separate map and keep track of which map belongs to which image. Thus, I tried the idea with the anchor-image.

Comment: Why is it a problem to make many maps? It sounds like they are generated, and not written by hand.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up doing them all separately.